# Post multiple lines with form laravel

Tags: php, sql, forms, laravel, frameworks

I work on laravel 5.2 and I list users from my database with a loop like this :

```
Name Phone category
toto 0606  categ1
tata 0707  categ2 
etc.
```

With category is an input select and we can choose the category.

All of this is in a form and when I click on "Submit" a the end of the page I want to post in database the category selected for each user and the current year. 
This must post in a table "category_relation" that contains the user's id, the category's id and current year but if there is already an entry with exactly the same informations, do nothing.

My question is : How to insert data to the table "category_relation" with fields user_id, category_id and the current_year with out repeating the relation?

I know I'm not very clear but if you have questions I will answer !

PS: I don't know if this will help but I have a relation between users and categories like this in my User  Model:

```
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\categories','HISTO_ID_USER', 'ID_USER');
    }
```

Thanks

**EDIT :**

My view :

```
<section class="panel panel-default">
    {{!! Form::open(['method' => 'post', 'url' => action('AffectAbcController@store')]) !!}}
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped m-b-none datatable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="no-sort">Photo</th>
                <th>Entrée</th>
                <th>Nom</th>
                <th>Prénom</th>
                <th>Site</th>
                <th>Pôle</th>
                <th>Equipe</th>    
                <th class="no-sort">Tél interne</th>
                <th>Affecter catégorie</th> 
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            @foreach ($personnels as $personnel)

                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $personnel->PERSO_ETAT}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $personnel->PERSO_DATE_ENTREE }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $personnel->PERSO_NOM_USAGE}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $personnel->PERSO_PRENOM }} </td>
                    <td>{{ $personnel->site["SITE_LIBELLE"]}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $personnel->pole["POLE_LIBELLE"]}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $personnel->equipe["EQUIPE_LIBELLE"]}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $personnel->PERSO_TELEPHONE}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <select class="form-input" name="category">
                            <option value="0"></option>
                            @foreach ($categories as $category)
                                @if(isset($personnel->lastAbc[0]))
                                    @if($personnel->lastAbc[0]["HISTO_AFFECT_ID_CATEG"]==$category->CATEG_ID_ABC)
                                        <option value='{{$category->CATEG_ID_ABC}}' selected="selected">{{$category->CATEG_CODE_ABC}} - {{$category->CATEG_LIBELLE_ABC }}</option>
                                    @else
                                        <option value='{{$category->CATEG_ID_ABC}}'>{{$category->CATEG_CODE_ABC}} - {{$category->CATEG_LIBELLE_ABC }}</option>
                                    @endif
                                @else
                                    <option value='{{$category->CATEG_ID_ABC}}'>{{$category->CATEG_CODE_ABC}} - {{$category->CATEG_LIBELLE_ABC }}</option>
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin:15px 0px;">Envoyer</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

My controller :

```
class AffectAbcController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{

            $personnels=Personnel::with('lastAbc','site','pole','equipe')->where('PERSO_DATE_SORTIE_CONTRAT', null)->get();
            $categories = Abc::all();
    return view('affectAbc.list', compact('personnels', 'categories'));
}

    public function store(){

    }

}
```

In this code "personnel" is an User.

Comment: You've to add your relevant HTML, so we can helps.

Comment: Thanks, it's done